# Closed ball is a closed set by showing that it's equal to its closure

Tags: general-topology

Given the Euclidean space ($\mathbb{R}^n, d_{\|\cdot\|_2}$), $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $r >0$,  I want to show that the closed ball
$B = \overline{B_{d_{\|\cdot\|_2}}(x,r)}$ is closed by showing that it is equal to its closure.

Clearly $B \subset \overline{B}$.

To show the opposite inclusion I let $y \in \overline{B}$, i.e. there exists a sequence $\{y_n\}$$_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$$ \subset B$ that converges to $y$. This means that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}: d_{\|\cdot\|_2}(x,y_n) \le r$ and that for sufficiently large $n$, $d_{\|\cdot\|_2}(y_n,y) < \varepsilon$.

Then, using triangle inequality
$d_{\|\cdot\|_2} (x,y) \le d_{\|\cdot\|_2} (x,y_n) + d_{\|\cdot\|_2}(y_n,y) < r + \varepsilon$.

Can I then just take the limit $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$ to complete the proof? If that's the case, how do I argue that the $<$ becomes a $\le$?

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because $d(x,y) < r+\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$, we have $d(x,y) \leq r$.  If this is not obvious, you can easily prove it by contradiction.

Comment: Thanks, do you agree with the rest of the proof?

Comment: Yes, looks good.